# Display 'Show Entries' dropdown below DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

Is there any way to have the `Show Entries` dropdown below the table using DataTables?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use [DOM Positioning](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html) to set the length changing element 'l' after the table 't' :

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "sDom": 'tl'
});
```